# Tool or Package For Designing Site For a Small Non-Profit Accepting Donations

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, e-commerce, squarespace

I deal primarily with custom .net WebForms and MVC based applications, but someone came to me and asked for help with creating a small website for their non-profit organization for which they will need to be able to accept donations.

My preference would be to use a simple CMS, and I have heard of Shopify and the Shop Plugin for WordPress, but they really don't need that level of e-commerce. Basically what I am looking for is some advice for using a simple mini-CMS, be it WordPress, Squarespace, etc, and integrating some method for accepting and keeping track of donations.

My initial thought was to use WordPress and then link to Paypal.

Comment: Ended up initially going with squarespace... then moved to Orchard...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: WordPress has grown up since a few years ago. It can easily be used as a full-on CMS serving hundreds of pages based on custom data types.

As far as collecting donations, any ecommerce/shopping cart solution is massive overkill for accepting donations. A PayPal link is definitely the fastest way to go. Here is a [step-by-step tutorial](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_donate-intro-outside) on how to do it.

Note: some people do not like PayPal, so consider adding multiple buttons. Here is the [Google Checkout](http://checkout.google.com/seller/npo/) version. Or 2co looks like [they will support it now](http://www.2checkout.com/public/general/accept-donations/#comments) (or Real Soon Now).

Comment: Looking into. Thanks for the recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

Squarespace - an alternative to wordpress. Get the complete guide - https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206796007-Templates-and-design

After your setup the website - Find the step-by-step guide on how to accept recurring donations on Squarespace website for your non-profit websites.
https://donorbox.org/nonprofit-blog/squarespace-embedding/